# How to check integrity of an encrypted string then converted to Base64?

Tags: asp.net

I encrypt and decrypt a string with a private key and following functions.
so I encrypt a string with Encrypt function and decrypt the encrypted string with decrypt function.
If someone can change the encrypted string and then it decrypts with decrypt function, the decrypted string isn't equal to plain text before encrypting.
I want to know how can I check is decrypted string equals to plain text before encrypting?

```
 public string Encrypt(string plainText, string password)
    {
        GenerateKey(password);
        return Encrypt(plainText);
    }
    public string Encrypt(string plainText)
    {
        if (Key == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Password must be provided or set.");
        }
        byte[] data = new UnicodeEncoding().GetBytes(plainText);
        RijndaelManaged crypto = new RijndaelManaged();
        ICryptoTransform encryptor = crypto.CreateEncryptor(Key, Vector);
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        CryptoStream crptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        crptoStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        crptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
        crptoStream.Close();
        memoryStream.Close();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());
    }
    public string Decrypt(string encryptedText, string password)
    {
        GenerateKey(password);
        return Decrypt(encryptedText);
    }
    public string Decrypt(string encryptedText)
    {

        if (Key == null)
        {

            throw new InvalidOperationException("Password must be provided or set.");
        }
        byte[] cipher = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedText);
        RijndaelManaged crypto = new RijndaelManaged();
        ICryptoTransform encryptor = crypto.CreateDecryptor(Key, Vector);
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(cipher);
        CryptoStream crptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
        byte[] data = new byte[cipher.Length];
        int dataLength = crptoStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
        memoryStream.Close();
        crptoStream.Close();
        return (new UnicodeEncoding()).GetString(data, 0, dataLength);
    }
```

Comment: May I ask if this is because you want a protection against someone hacking into your system and changing the encrypted string?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I encrypt a string in a webmethod and then store it in a Hidden field, but someone maybe see or change the value in hidden field and send it to server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embed a checksum. Take e.g. a SHA1 hash of the plaintext, base64 it, prepend it to the text and encrypt. After decrypting, extract the SHA1 part and verify it against the remainder of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include a [message authentication code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) (MAC).

The details of doing this correctly are beyond the scope of a SO answer so I suggest consulting an expert before starting an implementation.

A good starting point would by *[Practical Cryptography](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471223573)* (not specific to .NET or any other platform, but will show you what you need to do—and why it is very hard to get right).